# Unity. Get the current IMGUI drawing target. Screen or EditorWindow/Popup

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor, unity3d-editor, unity3d-gui

I'm developing a class that can draw the interface both in the game and in the editor.
Now I manually specify which mode to work. Because some functions are not available in different modes

```
class MyWindow : MonoBehaviour {
  void OnGUI() {
    myClass.OnGUI(GUIMode.Screen);
  }
}
 
class MyEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
  void OnGUI() {
    myClass.OnGUI(GUIMode.Inspector);
  }
}
```

I would like to learn how to detect this automatically. Is it possible?

What have already I tried: Google. Read documentation. Read Unity GUI-classes source code

Comment: Why must this be done automatically?

Comment: I It's comfortable.
I'm making a public library and if the user calls a function with the wrong parameter, it will seem to him that my library is simply broken. He won't even see errors or warnings that he is doing something wrong.

Comment: IDK the details of your library, but I think you should make 2 methods, one is `OnGUI` and another is `OnEditorGUI`. Like that Unity has `GUI` and `EditorGUI` classes.

Comment: Yes, I can do that. But this is the same as pass GUIMode in my example above.
User may make a mistake.
This is not such a big problem, but it’s nice when a mistake cannot be made at all.

Comment: For example. I can call GUI.Button() GUI.Lable() in editor and this work good. GUI.Window() work only for game screen but in editor will nothing happened. Even no error or warning. But there is no Button() in EditorGUI

Comment: Because there are so many differences, implementing both in a single method will make the code dirty in my opinion. And your requirement is hard to determine, AFAIK Unity does not have publicly available properties to distinguish which environment this method was called in. Maybe there are some tricks such as searching the stacktrace or checking `GUI.skin`, but they are not ideal. FYI, `GUI.Window` can work in an editor window, you need to call `EditorWindow.BeginWindows` first.

Comment: Of course my internal implementation has two functions inside: OnGUI() and OnEditorGUI(). But there is no one reason to call OnGUI() from editor or call OnEditorGUI() from screen. Thanks for BeingWindow this is useful for me

Comment: I don't think there is a reliable way to always know the intent of the user and why he calls some function. To a certain level you have to expect the user to know what he is doing. Maybe instead of a parameter create 2 methods to make the difference more clear.

Comment: Great. you convinced me. thank you everyone!

Answer (score 0):

There are [scripting symbols](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) you can use to conditionally compile things.
They can also be used to determine specific configurations of the environment, and set variables.
eg.

```
private bool isEditor;
...
#if UNITY_EDITOR

isEditor = true;

#endif
```

For specifically checking if you are in the editor, you can use the flag [isEditor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-isEditor.html) from the Application class.

```
if (Application.isEditor)
{
    Debug.Log("In Editor");
}
else
{
    Debug.Log("In Build");
}
```

There are more flags in the [Application](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.html) class to determine common environment context, such as `isMobilePlatform`, `isConsolePlatform`, `platform`, etc.

Comment: No, sorry but this is not a solution